# Passing session while switching control to a pop-up window

Tags: selenium, webdriver, c#

I am trying to choose a date by clicking an image which results in a pop-up window with a date picker in it.But when done through selenium the session expires and the login page appears in the pop-up window.How to pass the current session of the base window to the pop-up window?I am writing my test using C# and Webdriver 2.0.

Comment: Does it do the same with all browsers or just the one?

Comment: Siddharth -Are you testing the date picker itself or do you just need to set the date?  If you just need to set the date to move through the functionality of the page can you set the date in field?

Comment: i am also having same problem.......................................

Comment: @tester I converted this to a comment, since that's really what it is. Could you perhaps elaborate on how your situation is similar, or perhaps what progress you may have made on the problem?

Comment: Are you still facing the same issue?

Comment: Do you have a code example of whats happening?  Is the session stored in a cookie or in the URL when its passed? Does this fail only in webdriver or also manually?